# Are there any halakhic concerns with mustache wax?

Tags: hukot-hagoyim, beard

Are there halachic concerns with using wax to remove a mustache off of someone's lip?

Does it make a difference if it is for aesthetic appeal or some other reason?

Could this be considered *chukat goyim*?

Comment: A belated welcome to Mi Yodeya. Please note that we don’t accept questions asking for practical Halacha, and as such, this is likely to be closed.

Comment: I allowed myself to edit to avoid this question being closed. You can [edit] further as you please or roll back my edits

Comment: Mustache is meykar Hadin allowed to shave with a razor blade!

Comment: Old yekes had a beard and no mustache

Comment: @mbloch [Please don’t.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4774/9682)

Comment: In Nazir 58b & 59a mustache is not mentioned at all, pubis and axillary hair only

Comment: @DonielF do you have an issue if I roll back my edits now - after 24 hours passed - which was the delay suggested at the top answer of your meta question ?

Comment: @mbloch That's not what the top answer suggested. What he suggested was 24 hours after it was *closed*. I don't understand why this isn't closed yet, anyway.

Comment: @DonielF even more reason to roll back then :-> My question to you is if you have an issue if I do this. Don't want to play a tag game of rollback with you nor do I want to do it if it annoys you. But I have improved my answer to the question and would like to undelete it. Generalizing the question makes it more interesting for all and less of a RfP

Comment: @DonielF Seeing as you think the question should otherwise be closed, I think it should be edited (as mbloch did) to match your standards if that could salvage it. [This meta post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4025/1569) is more relevant than the one you linked, and the top two answers as I understand them are for editing in this case

Comment: @DonielF, I don't read this question as a request for Psak, I read this as "are there Halachic issues" to make a more educated question to a Rabbi. Anyone can go pasken from anything written here. The question doesn't ask "can I" it just provides honest motivation.

Answer (score 1):

Waxing to shave is permitted in general, see e.g., [here](https://thetorah.com/the-prohibition-of-shaving/) from R Zev Farber

> According to the [halacha](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.181.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) [...] it is forbidden for a man
>   to shave off the hair of his temples or to shave off the corners of
>   his beard. Both of these rules apply only to shaving with a razor.
>   Using a depilating cream, **a waxing process**, or just pulling the
>   hair out by hand would not be forbidden. Trimming with scissors and
>   most forms of electric shavers (where the razor does not touch the
>   face) are not forbidden either.

In general, doing something that other Jews do is not *chukat goyim* (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/536/11501) on MY).

There is no issue of [*lo yilbash gever simlat isha*](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.22.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (to act in the way of women) either because this applies to beautifying oneself in the way of women or wearing women garments.

I checked the above with R Binyamin Tabady who concurs that waxing to remove a mustache is permitted.

For further reading and sources see also [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13042/11501) and [there](http://dinonline.org/2011/05/02/removing-body-haireyebrows/).